# REGEX for characters numbers and All Chars, numbers and ~_&*%@$

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Hi i am kinda a newbie here, i need to write a **regex** for a textbox allowing All Chars, numbers and ~_&*%@$

i tried this ,which will allow only characters and no.

```
 /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers and ~_&*%@$ are already included in "all chars", as they are "chars". I'm going to assume that you meant "English alphabet".

In which case, you want:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9~_&*%@$]*$/
```

Comment: is there any possibility to restrict user to enter in a text box as http://www.google.com ?